# Me está fallando la lectura de datos char en una arreglo de cadenas

Tags: c++, string

Estoy haciendo una arreglo de cadenas para guardar los nombres y apellidos de estudiantes, pero cuando lo corro no deja leer el primer valor, pueden ayudarme a solucionar ese error?
Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int alumnos = 0, materia = 0;
    
    cout<<"\tNOTAS DE ALUMNOS.\n";
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de los alumnos: "; cin>>alumnos;
    cout<<"Ingrese el materias: "; cin>>materia;
    cout<<"Nombres de las materias: "<<endl;
    
    char nombre_apellido[alumnos][101] = {}, Materias[alumnos][41] = {} ;
    char materiaMax[41] = "",materiaMin[41] = "";
    float notas[alumnos][5] = {}, Promedios[alumnos] = {};
    float suma = 0, promedio = 0, PromedioFinal= 0, x, max = 0, min = 30;
    
    for(int i=0; i<alumnos; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin.getline(nombre_apellido[i],101,'\n');
    }
```

Cuando lo corro sale esto:

```
NOTAS DE ALUMNOS.
Ingrese el numero de los alumnos: 3
Ingrese el materias: 5
Nombres de las materias:
Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno 1: Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno 2:
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en las etiquetas con qué lenguaje estás trabajando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de leer el valor para la variable `materia`, el carácter de nueva línea quedará en el buffer y cuando se invoca la función `getline()`, leerá el carácter de nueva línea y omitirá la entrada.

Esto ocurre en la función `getline()` en dos momentos.

1 - Cuando la función es invocada para leer el valor de la variable materia.
2- Al llamar a la función que lee el nombre del alumno.

Al presionar `Enter` después de escribir el texto, el carácter `Enter` se coloca en el buffer de entrada, lo que hace que la función g`etline()` lea el carácter Enter y salte la entrada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> #add
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int alumnos = 0, materia = 0;

    cout << "\tNOTAS DE ALUMNOS.\n";
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de los alumnos: ";
    cin >> alumnos;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de materias: ";
    cin >> materia;

    
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');#1
    cin.clear(); #2

    cout << "Nombres de las materias: " << endl;

    char nombre_apellido[alumnos][101] = {}, Materias[materia][41] = {};
    char materiaMax[41] = "", materiaMin[41] = "";
    float notas[alumnos][5] = {}, Promedios[alumnos] = {};
    float suma = 0, promedio = 0, PromedioFinal = 0, x, max = 0, min = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i < alumnos; i++) {
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre y apellido del alumno " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(nombre_apellido[i], 101, '\n');
    }

    

    return 0;
   }
```

`cin.ignore()` : ( #1 ) Limpia el búfer de entrada.

`cin.clear()` : ( #2 ) Limpia el error del búfer de entrada.

`numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` : El valor máximo posible para el tipo streamsize.

Comment: Solo necesitas limpiar el error si hay uno.  En este caso solo sucede si al leer `alumnos` o `materias` se ingresa algo que no sea un número.